# Error while loading url with service worker and self signed certificate in a webview

Tags: android, webview, service-worker, self-signed

I am trying to load a local host url in Android web view with https using a self signed certificate. The web application has service workers that needs to be registered. But when I am loading the url in web view I am getting the SSL handshake error. I tried to by pass the ssl checking by using `handler.proceed();` in the `onReceivedSslError()` . But the error is still there . Any help on this ?

```
Error : I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Error during service worker registration:",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing and trusting the TLS cert or cert authority.  Then, any sites using those certs will not prompt for SSL/TLS warnings.